# Seamless way to have touch be mapped to Input.mousePosition again in new input system

Tags: unity

had not expected such a basic mapping to not come as default... what is the simplest way to do that simple mapping - that does not require modifying existing scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the new input system is to stop using the legacy `Input` class entirely. It's a full replacement, not just a few extra features.

If you want legacy scripts relying on `Input` to keep working unchanged, you can run both input systems under `Project Settings > Player > Active Input Handling`, as shown in [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.7/manual/Installation.html):

[image: Enabling both input systems]

This means you're asking your Unity game to do twice as much work piping input through two different systems every frame. It's OK during early migration and testing, but I'd strongly recommend biting the bullet and editing the old scripts so everything in your project uses the same input system.

Comment: i tried automatically updating the old scripts but everything is broken on mobile... Both seems to have some things working others not working

Comment: Then post a question about how to fix one of those scripts. You're a game developer - "automatic update" is a nice convenience when it works, but it's far from the only option available to you.